# Wait for one of two processes in shell script

Tags: shell

I am running a couple of background processes in my shell script. I want to exit the script when one of the two processes exit.

If I apply:

```
wait $PID1
wait $PID2
```

It'll will wait for process 1 to complete and then wait for process 2. Same happens for:

```
command 1 && command 2 && wait
```

Is there any way I could perform an or operation on the wait command?

Comment: I believe `bash` v4.3 has a `wait -n` to wait for any process to complete....

Answer (score 1):

You can trap SIGCHLD:

```
trap 'exit 0' SIGCHLD
```

Comment: @Amriteya This installs a signal handler in the shell for SIGCHLD, the signal that is sent by the kernel to a parent process whenever one of its child processes exits. So the first of the two processes causes a SIGCHLD, the handler gets called, and the exit 0 is executed, exiting the shell script. You should install the handler before you start the children.